# Kendo-UI Grid (w/ MVC Wrappers) : How do I create a button that navigates to details page

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have been working with the Kendo UI for ASP.NET MVC suite and can't figure out how to do something that I feel is very simple.

I have a basic grid that loads customer information: Name, Phone, Fax, Website, etc.
I want the far right column to be an edit button that simply calls the Details Action Result passing it the id of the current row that it is clicked from.

I really didn't want to have to resort to asking this on here, but all of the examples deal with inline editing and popup editing.

Below is my current code:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<CustomerViewModel>()
.Name("CustomerGrid")
.Columns(columns => {
    columns.Bound(c => c.Name);
    columns.Bound(c => c.Phone);
    columns.Bound(c => c.Fax);
    columns.Bound(c => c.Website);
})
.Pageable(pageable => pageable
    .Refresh(true)
    .PageSizes(true)
    .ButtonCount(5))
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax()
    .Read(read => read.Action("Customers_Read", "Customer"))
))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Solution

   ```
   @(Html.Kendo().Grid<CustomerViewModel>()
   .Name("CustomerGrid")
   .Columns(columns => {
       columns.Bound(c => c.Name).ClientTemplate("" + @Html.ActionLink("#: Name#", "ViewCompanyDetails", "Company", new {companyId = "#: CompanyId#"}, new {Title = "View #: CompanyName#"}) + "");
       columns.Bound(c => c.Phone);
       columns.Bound(c => c.Fax);
       columns.Bound(c => c.Website);
   })
   .Pageable(pageable => pageable
       .Refresh(true)
       .PageSizes(true)
       .ButtonCount(5))
   .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
       .Ajax()
       .Read(read => read.Action("Customers_Read", "Customer"))
   ))
   ```
2. Solution

   ```
   @(Html.Kendo().Grid<CustomerViewModel>()
   .Name("CustomerGrid")
   .Columns(columns => {
       columns.Bound(c => c.Phone);
       columns.Bound(c => c.Fax);
       columns.Bound(c => c.Website);
       columns.Command(command => command.Custom("ViewDetails").Click("location.href='@Url.Action("ViewCustomerDetail", "Customer", new { CustomerId = #=CustomerId# })'"));

   })
   .Pageable(pageable => pageable
       .Refresh(true)
       .PageSizes(true)
       .ButtonCount(5))
   .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
       .Ajax()
       .Read(read => read.Action("Customers_Read", "Customer"))
   ))
   ```

Comment: Thank you very much. I haven't tested this yet but I'm assuming it will make it so the customer's name links to the customer details page. Is there any way to easily do it with the grid edit button or a custom command button?

Comment: Works great I had a feeling it would just be some MVC razor code plaved in a grid template. Thanks again.

Comment: Solution 2 is causing an error. I tried to fix up the quotes but it's erroring: `columns.Command(command => command.Custom("ViewDetails").Click("location.href='" + @Url.Action("Details", "Customer", new { id = "#: CustomerID#" }) + "'"));`

Comment: You can always make a javascript function...columns.Command(command => command.Custom("ViewDetails").Click("ViewClickFunction").

Comment: Yeah I tried making a js function that accepts the customers id and does location.href and I placed it in .Click("VewDetails("#: CustomerID#")"). Does that look right? Also I meant to ask what is the diff between #= and #: tags? You used #= in solution 2. Sorry to bug you again buddy.

Comment: you can use #:# or #= # print values of column they are reserve keyword for kendo Ui framework. more info http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/getting-started/framework/templates/overview